# symmetricsDS and postgresql

Tags: postgresql, symmetricds

I wan't to  replicate two  databases with symmetricDS,
First, i try to do this tutorial https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.8/html/tutorials.html

i have install symmetricDs I have installed symmetricDS on my postgresql serveur.

and execute this commands  :

```
    ../bin/dbimport --engine corp-000 --format XML --alter-case create_sample.xml
    ../bin/symadmin --engine corp-000 create-sym-tables
    ../bin/dbimport --engine corp-000 insert_sample.sql
       bin/sym
```

But No tables was write in my database, and no symmetric table too

Can't you help ?

Comment: Could you please upload your engines files for the nodes?  You might have an error there.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the user account provided to connect your SymmetricDS nodes has the ability to create tables.   Then I would check the symmetric.log for any obvious errors. By default it would create the tables in the default schema of the user account provided so be sure to check that schema for the tables.